# Convert ACF checkbox choices to links

Tags: php

I'm using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) to create a checkbox on a custom post. Does anyone know if it's possible to turn those checkbox choices into links? For example:

> **Checkbox Results:**
>
> ~ Red <- links to a post about the color red.
>
> ~ Blue <- links to a post about the color blue.
>
> ~ Green <- links to a post about the color green.

If anyone can help, that would be awesome:)

Thanks!

Comment: I've tried running an IF statement (ie, IF word is "example" then link to "/example". But I'm almost 100% sure that's the most wrong way to do it ha ha:) What I'm trying now is to put the link as the Value of the checkbox choice. Just trying to mentally work it out to see if it could work

Comment: Where do you want the link to end up? In the Post Content?

Comment: Thanks to whoever down-voted me. I thought my question was appropriate enough. Anyways, what I'm using now is this:

`echo '<li>' . '<a href=' . $value . '>' . $value . '</a>' . '</li>';`

Comment: @Douglas.Sesar I need the links to be dynamically created. So if I add "red" as an option, I will then create a post called "red" that will then be linked, as in my code above.

Comment: The links are purely for explanations, so what I might do is create one "glossary" page, and then do something like: 

`echo '<li>' . '<a href="glossary/#"' . $value . '>' . $value . '</a>' . '</li>';`

Answer (score 1):

Here is my final solution for anyone else facing the same problem:

```
<?php
$values = get_field('services');
if($values)
  {
  echo '<ul>';
  foreach($values as $value)
  {
  echo '<li>' . '<a href="glossary/#' . strtolower(str_replace(' ', '_', $value)) . '"' . '>' . $value . '</a>' . '</li>';
   }
  echo '</ul>';
  }
?>
```